# Can I speed up AHK key press?

Tags: autohotkey

I have written the following script, which will eventually be part of a longer script with similar sets of keystrokes - pressing two keys simultaneously to trigger a single keystroke:

```
j & k:: Send {F9}
j::Send {j}
k::Send {k}
```

The script works fine except that (1) it seems that the associated F9 function (pause/play) is ever-so-slightly slower compared to if I pressed F9 directly.

But even more frustrating is that when I press "j" or "k" alone, I have to wait a bit for the key to register. Otherwise, it skips the key (e.g., typing "Karen" ends up with "aren"). That quirk renders the script useless for my purposes. Is there any way to speed up the response time of the script?

My main objective here is to be able to use home row keys to trigger hotkeys assigned to the F keys, to avoid having to reach for the F keys (and thus leave the home row). I do a lot of video/audio transcription, and I strictly use hotkeys (haven't used a foot pedal in 20 years). Although I use many different transcription apps, I consistently use the same customized hotkey assignments across all the apps. So F9, for example, is always for pause/play. That has worked fine for decades, but it occurred to me today that since my mechanical keyboard (Corsair K95 RGB) has n-key rollover, I might be able to speed things up by assigning two simultaneous (easier to reach) keys on the home row to press the F keys (which I use for the hotkeys).

I am a super-fast typist (150+), so anything that causes a lag in keyboard response time throws me completely off course. This script would be ideal if I could get it to execute faster. Thanks in advance. Any and all suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you primarily plan to use "jk" while editing text? If so, this might work for you:

```
~j & k::  Send {BS}{F9}
```

The tilde ensures j will always be sent and without delay. {BS} erases the unneeded j when it's used as part of the hotkey sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [this link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm), I believe this is your solution:

`SetKeyDelay, 0`